# Get jQuery dropdown value onchange event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I load partialview on load page .

```
$(window).bind("load",
 function() {
  $.get("/agent/GetInfo",
   function(data) {
   $("#home-tab-right").empty();
   $("#home-tab-right").append(data);
  });
});
```

I have a dropdown on partialview. I want to run a function on change it. I use this code but don't run it.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#StateId').change(function() {
            var item = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("FindCity", "Agent")',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { value: item },
                success: function(result) {
                    $("#CityId").find('option').remove();
                    $.each(result,
                        function(i) {
                            var optionhtml = '<option value="' +
                                result[i].Id +
                                '">' +
                                result[i].Name +
                                '</option>';
                            $("#CityId").append(optionhtml);
                        });
                    $(".popup-loading").hide();
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: `$(document).on("change","#StateId",function(){ //process })`

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid attaching the same event multiple times. Use Off() first

```
$(document).off("change.findCity").on("change.findCity","#StateId",function(){ //process })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (event) {
        $('#StateId').on('change', function (event) {

          //do something
         });
    });
</script>
```